# layout doesn't load until end of method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, oncreate

I'm having an issue with an acitivity for an android app, to make it simple I let there be three activities : the main M, the one that answers A and the one I start C.

So M starts A using startActivityOnResult, then A sends result to M and from there M starts S.

But for some reason, the layout of S doesn't update until the main method I call from there is finished (and when that method is finished the activity goes back to M anyway, so basically I only see the layout if I make the activity S not give the result and stand there doing nothing).

Here is some of the code :

In M starting S :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, getCamFind.class);

    intent.putExtra("path", mCurrentPhotoPath);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMFIND_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In S :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_getcamfind);
    receivedIntent = getIntent();
    Log.d(TAG, "Received string : " + receivedIntent.getStringExtra("path"));

}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    try {
        postCamResult(receivedIntent.getStringExtra("path"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So here the main method I was talking about is postCamResult, it basically connects to a server using retrofit. At the end of this method is where I would usually put the few lines to send back the result intent. The problem being the layout waits for this method to finish for some reason ? so if I don't send the result intent, it will, after doing all the server related stuff, finally print my layout, but you know, I'd like my layout to appear as soon as I open the activity!

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The Android documentation for the Activity lifecycle states that the visible lifetime of an Activity is between *onStart()* and *onStop()*, so the layout you set will be rendered after the onStart method is done.
If you put your *postCamResult()* inside *onResume()* you should be fine.

Still connecting to a server on the UI Thread is a bad idea, you should start a seperate thread for that, otherwise you might get an anr.

Comment: Yeah I know about the thread thing, I'm just testing around a bit. Your solution didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: Moving the call from `onStart()` to `onResume()` isn't going to help. You need to get the network I/O off the main thread. This is stopping the UI from updating. If you put the contents of `postCamResult()` into a background thread you should see your layout right away.

Comment: My bad, eventhough the activity is visible to the user between `onStart()` and `onStop()`, the renderer might not be done rendering the layout so you have to use a background Thread as David suggested.

Comment: So I went on and made a background thread, and now something really peculiar happens, the layout goes back to the main activity while the thread does the server request, so the S activity layout never appears at all ? I tried calling the thread from both onResume and onCreate to see if it made any difference but nothing.